# Messages app on Mac syncing text messages but not iMessages

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, macos, messages

I am encountering problems syncing iMessages with my Mac. I can send and receive text messages and iMessages on my iPhone. I cannot send and receive iMessages on my Macbook, but I can send and receive text messages on my Macbook.

My Messages app on Mac was working perfectly until I deleted items in my Keychain. I repaired and verified my Keychain afterwards, too. I did do a hard restart and removed all my accounts on my Mac and added them back. I also deleted my iCloud account and re-added it.

I have also disabled iMessages on my iPhone, then re-enabled it. Also de-paired and re-paired my iPhone and Macbook connection for iMessages. I still get the same behavior.

Does anyone have any idea what to do? I have googled and tried everything...

Anytime I send an iMessage through the Messages app, I get the "not delivered!" notice. Is there an error log I can check for iMessages that might give me hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The messages app on the Mac has it's own preferences. Check if you're iMessage account is set up there and has a password set – perhaps you deleted it through keychain. If that doesn't help remove it with the minus and re-add the account.

Comment: You know, the funny thing is that it won't let me remove my account through the the Messages app. The "-" is greyed out. I did sign out and sign back in and no go.